# Permutation method for number sequence from 1 to N without arrays, java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, permutation

Please help me to find out how to write method that prints all possible combination of numbers from 1 to N. I can't use arrays, collections or strings.
I need output like that (for 3):

```
 [1]  [2]  [3] 
 [1]  [3]  [2] 
 [2]  [1]  [3] 
 [2]  [3]  [1] 
 [3]  [2]  [1] 
 [3]  [1]  [2]
```

There is no problem to write such method using array:

```
public class Test {

static void permute(int[] a, int k) {
    if (k == a.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" [" + a[i] + "] ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        for (int i = k; i < a.length; i++) {
            int temp = a[k];
            a[k] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;

            permute(a, k + 1);

            temp = a[k];
            a[k] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int N = 3;
    int[] sequence = new int[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sequence[i] = i + 1;
    }

    permute(sequence, 0);

}
```

}

Thanks in advance for any help!

UPD 1. I'm also trying to write something like this (but unsuccessful):

```
public class Combinations {

private static int change;

public void doIt(int n, int pos) {

    if (pos == n) {
        for (int f = 1; f <= n; f++) {
            System.out.print(f + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    } else {

        for (int i = pos; i < n; i++) {
            change = pos;
            System.out.print(change + " ");
            pos = i;
            System.out.print(pos + " ");
            i = change;
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            System.out.println("");

            doIt(n, pos + 1);

            change = pos;
            System.out.print(change + " ");
            pos = i;
            System.out.print(pos + " ");
            i = change;
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            System.out.println("");

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system might prove useful.

Comment: Hint: Use `print` inside your method, without newline except where appropriate.

Comment: Recursion might be your answer.

Comment: @Floris I agree with you but I need some hint for this. In UPD I wrote my attempt of such method. I have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: Can you use a bitmap to mark the numbers already printed?

Comment: Given the restriction on using "arrays, collections or strings" I presume that the solution desired would not rely on data structures in general -- including the BitSet class or custom-written collection-like classes. But does the restriction also forbid use of primitive data types like int or long as bit sets (by considering them very compact data structures) or recursion (by considering it using the call stack as a data structure)? Where does the restriction come from?

Comment: @JaeHeonLee I'm trying to do an excercise. And it wants me to write such  method without arrays, strings, collections. No more restrictions. Do you think it's possible at all?

Comment: @VasylHoshovsky At the risk of sounding repetitive -- so long as by _collections_ is meant classes within Java's [collections framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/), then it is probably in principle trivial (though in practice somewhat cumbersome) to reproduce your array-using solution with, say, [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)s. But otherwise I am not quite sure whether the problem has a solution, though my intuition is that it should be doable. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you could use [Factoradics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Permutations) (you can see an implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/higuaro/8394933)) or the [Knuth's L-Algorithm](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_bLHHR6rd5Ug/Sxn2isijPNI/AAAAAAAAAK8/1oSWhhjB7AI/s1600-h/AlgorithmL20.gif) that generates all permutations. The following is an implementation of the later (works in place):

```
public class Perm {
    private static int factorial(int n) {
        int fact = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            fact *= i;
        }
        return fact;
    }

    private static void swap(int[] elements, int i, int j) {
        int temp = elements[i];
        elements[i] = elements[j];
        elements[j] = temp;
    }

    /**
     * Reverses the elements of an array (in place) from the start index to the end index 
     */
    private static void reverse(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        int size = endIndex + 1 - startIndex;
        int limit = startIndex + size / 2;
        for (int i = startIndex; i < limit; i++) {
            // swap(array, i, startIndex + (size - 1 - (i - startIndex)));
            swap(array, i, 2 * startIndex + size - 1 - i);
        }
    }

    private static void printSequence(int[] sequence) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d, ", sequence[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * Implements the Knuth's L-Algorithm permutation algorithm 
     * modifying the collection in place
     */
    private static void permutations(int[] sequence) {
        final int N = sequence.length;
        // There are n! permutations, but the first permutation is the array without 
        // modifications, so the number of permutations is n! - 1
        int numPermutations = factorial(N) - 1;

        // For every possible permutation 
        for (int n = 0; n < numPermutations; n++) {

            // Iterate the array from right to left in search 
            // of the first couple of elements that are in ascending order
            for (int i = N - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
                // If the elements i and i - 1 are in ascending order
                if (sequence[i - 1] < sequence[i]) {
                    // Then the index "i - 1" becomes our pivot index 
                    int pivotIndex = i - 1;

                    // Scan the elements at the right of the pivot (again, from right to left)
                    // in search of the first element that is bigger
                    // than the pivot and, if found, swap it
                    for (int j = N - 1; j > pivotIndex; j--) {
                        if (sequence[j] > sequence[pivotIndex]) {
                            swap(sequence, j, pivotIndex);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Now reverse the elements from the right of the pivot index
                    // (this nice touch to the algorithm avoids the recursion)
                    reverse(sequence, pivotIndex + 1, N - 1);
                    break;
                }
            }

            printSequence(sequence);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        final int N = 3;
        int[] sequence = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            sequence[i] = i + 1;
        }

        printSequence(sequence);
        permutations(sequence);
    }
}
```

Hope the comments guide you in the understanding of the algorithm.